# Kafka setup and trading engine taking fee

Tags: python, apache-kafka, trading, algorithmic-trading, forex

We are currently setting up a trading engine and have basically got everything setup in regards to how it should function the only part we are struggling on figuring out is how the fee should be removed and what config to use for kafka

This is how it currently works
Users sends request -> goes to balance engine and reserves balance if enough -> sends confirmation back of reserved amount and pushes order to kafka queue -> matching engine matches the amount reserved -> updated users balance and enters into database the transaction and would take fee here (this is the fee problem here) -> if anything still left over to trade at price it will then place into order book.

Order book is using redis in memory for fast database and matching and everything else is basically sorted.

Our two issues are how would you setup kafka to be able to have a individual balance queue per a user would it be best to do 1 topic and each use has their own partition which I belive would be limited to only 10,000 users having their own balance queue or would there be any other better way?
And the other thing is how can we remove the fee as we have looked at other exchanges like binance, kucoin and etc and they seem to take the fee off after the trade has matched and when they are processing the balance however in doing so it means it trades more then it should because of the fee to be taken. Like in the example below

**user buying =**

price: 1 btc

amount: 100 nano to buy

total: 100 btc to pay  (no fee taken off yet)

**user selling but in order book =**

price 1 btc

amount: 100 nano nano to sell

total: 100 btc to receive  (no fee taken off)

So the match happens and basically matches 1:1 however now it comes to updating balance and fee is to be taken off and we get the following problem where there is 0.1 nano traded extra that should of stayed in order book due to the 0.1% fee.

Since user 1 would be really trading 99.9 btc as the 0.1 btc fee taken off which means he would be getting really 99.9 nano however matching engine traded full amount with no fee taken off so an extra 0.1 was traded that was the fee so it causes a lot of issues.

How would this be done so on trading the extra 0.1 nano gets left in order book if all the fees removal is at end of a trade been matched and traded.

The other factor is we have the option to pay in another coin and this check needs to be at the end so it does not reserve that coins amount when adding to balance and removing from reserve and calculating fee it checks if pay in that coin was enabled and if so it will then check if the user has enough of that coin at the time. If they do then it uses that to pay fee if not then uses the normal base pair fee.

Its not a complex issue buts its been a big pain to try figure out how to integrate fees into a system like this without causing issues and causing problems with matching times and amount users get.

If anyone has any clues it would be very good and helpful regarding best way for kafka and then fee integration.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: you have maker and taker. 

you always deduct the fee *after* the event happens from the amount he gets credited to his balance

1 BTC = 10_000$

bruno sells 1 BTC
peter buys 1 BTC
since they are matching 
peter goes +1.0000 BTC and bruno goes + 10_000$. just credit each of them the amount after fee. so peter gets 0.99 BTC and bruno gets 9900$.

Comment: alternatively, for the user with 1 BTC, if he has more $ left, you can deduct him 100$ fee from his USD balance so he can keep the 1 BTC rather than pay fee in BTC